# Converting UTM coordinates to WGS 84

Tags: coordinate-system, google-maps, coordinates, wgs84, epsg

I know the coordinates below are in UTM 36N (due to the EPSG code), and I can convert them with several websites online to wgs 84 and see them in Google Maps. However, been helplessly looking the internet for the conversion function itself, but found none.

```
<EPSGCode>32636</EPSGCode>
<Eastings>750400</Eastings>
<Northings>3000500</Northings>
```

Any idea how to convert those to WGS 84?

Comment: which language do you want?

Comment: javascript preferrably. can handle also python, java, c#...

Comment: Lots coordinate operations can be found from the EPSG database  http://www.ogp.org.uk/pubs/373-07-2.pdf

Comment: @user30184 : Your link is broken as of February 1st 2019

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For javascript you can use [proj4.js](http://proj4js.org/). Its conversion function is called proj4.